# CODEIGNITER How CI could read model name even if it is different

Tags: codeigniter, model, continuous-integration

I have a 'Event_Model'. I used it on a controller. I called it as

```
$this->load->model('Event_model','eventM')
```

I wrote the code with phpstorm on Window but it is running on a linux VM.
It worked on a local server. I got an error when I had uploaded on a linux production server though.
Why did it happen?
I don't understand how my local server could read it

```
use COMMON\Models\Event\Event_Comm_Model as Common_Event_Model;
class Event_Model extends Common_Event_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

The model is like this.

Comment: check files naming conventions: Class names must start with an uppercase letter. so do the filenames, which means the model event_model.php needs to be named Event_model.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux servers and hosted sites are very sensitive to file names. Make sure you respect the case sensitivity.

This can work on your local machine

`$this->load->model('Event_model','eventM')`

but for a hosted server use instead

`$this->load->model('Event_Model','eventM')`